# Trailing slashes: yes or no?

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, uri

I'm working on a new project, using Apache's mod_rewrite and PHP to get pretty URLs.

Here's what my URLs look like:
`http://example.tld/foo/bar/1/etc`

Notice that there's no trailing slash (that's the way I write it in the `href` attributes of `<a>`s).

However, I'm also allowing `http://example.tld/foo/bar/1/etc/` (trailing slash).

Is this bad practice? I'm wondering if it would be better to only allow one way or if I'd better use trailing slashes in all my links, by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trailing slash usually indicates a directory, without a trailing slash it indicates a file.

Allowing both with and without trailing slash will have a negative effect on your search engine ranking, because the same content is indexed twice. Stick to one, and do a 301 redirect if a user requests the other.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I just realized that Stack Overflow, for example, allows both trailing slashes and no trailing slashes. I think I'm going for no trailing slashes then. There are no browsers that try to force a trailing slash, right?

Answer (score 7):

Trailing slashes can be a problem when using relative links in the document, as the browser will then treat `/etc` as a directory.

I would define one way, and set up an external redirect for the other.

Comment: Relative links in pretty urls? Now there is an invitation to a headache.

Comment: @Kristoffer true :) But I've seen it done...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say for consistency only allow what you use yourself, then have it redirect ([301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)) the wrong (with trailing) to the right one (without trailing), this way you won't have [duplicate content](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66359) either.

Of course whats right and wrong is entirely up to you.